# add a tooltip with current .val to nouislider

Tags: jquery, slider, tooltip

I've currently got a project (codepen) - http://codepen.io/sturobson/pen/70f2fd8d19fdc76f136f905146218328 
that uses the nouislider - http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

I've got it working how I want but need to add a tooltip to it displaying the current .val of this slider.

I've currently got

```
$('#sample-showcase').noUiSlider({
  range : [40,500],
  start : 180,
  step : 10,
  handles : 1,
  slide : function() {
    $('.noUi-handle').append('<span class="tooltip"><span data-replace=".length-slider"></span> Months</span>');
    $('[data-replace]').each(function() {
      var replacer = $(this).data('replace');
      var text = $(replacer).val();
      $(this).text(text);
    });
  }
});
```

where in the slide bit I've got a span being appended.

This works ok but I can't get 
a) the value to display and b) it to update rather than continually repeat the append.

I'm really struggling with this and any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
$slider = $('#sample-showcase').noUiSlider({
  range : [40,500],
  start : 180,
  step : 10,
  handles : 1
}

$tooltip = $('<div class="noUi-value" />')
handle = $slider.data('base').data('handles')[0]
handle.append($tooltip);
```

and CSS

```
.noUi-value {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 60px;
    font: bold 10px Verdana;
    text-align: center;
}
.noUi-active+.noUi-value, .noUi-state-tap .noUi-value {
    display: block;
}
```